# Android Permission BLUETOOTH Manifest error

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

Following is the AndroidManifest.xml for a Simple Bluetooth pairing Android Project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothglassend"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
        android:maxSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Although not required, I've added permissions for all BLUETOOTH parameters I can find. Yet, I get this error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH permission: Neither user 10145 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH.
```

Any Ideas?

As an additional note, I imported this project in Android Studio from Intellij

Comment: Have you tried removing the android:maxSdkVersion="19" from the permission tag?

Comment: try adding this    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="true" /> and see if this working

Comment: @dora : Thanks, removing the android:maxSdkVersion worked. I am not sure why it did though, considering that's the target API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maxSdkVersion attribute version is for telling the highest API level at which this permission should be granted to your app. Setting this attribute is useful if the permission your app requires is no longer needed beginning at a certain API level.

For example, beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), it's no longer necessary for your app to request the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission when your app wants to write to its own application-specific directories on external storage (the directories provided by getExternalFilesDir()). However, the permission is required for API level 18 and lower. So you can declare that this permission is needed only up to API level 18 with a declaration such as this:

```
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

This way, beginning with API level 19, the system will no longer grant your app the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

So the error was that even lollipop needs you to ask permission for accessing bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, I had it figured. I'll accept your answer anyways for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a pretty straightforward solution. I was testing on Android Lollipop ( > maxSdkVersion ) hence the error.