# Apps starts crashing since end december 2016 at setPairingConfirmation because of missing BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions, bluetooth-lowenergy

After pairing with a BLE device the function `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.setPairingConfirmation` is called and this makes the app crash:

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10168 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
       at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.setPairingConfirmation(IBluetooth.java:1566)
       at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.setPairingConfirmation(BluetoothDevice.java:1182)
       at nl.myapp.ui.main.NotificationFragment.onDeviceSelected(SourceFile:374)
       at nl.myapp.ui.main.FindGlassDialogFragment.onDeviceClicked(SourceFile:224)
       at nl.myapp.ui.main.adapters.DeviceAdapter$2.onClick(SourceFile:61)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)`

The app was working fine when it was developed.
When I turn the the line `device.setPairingConfirmation()` off the app is working but the bluetooth device does not stop its pairing mode.

I have

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

in my manifest and i ask for the runtime permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in Android versions M and higher.

I tried asking for BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED as a runtime permission but they do not prompt a dialog.

Is this a bug in the current Android version? I'm sure the app was not crashing when it was released in on the 13th of december.

It occurs on Android 6 and 7.
I tested it on a Nexus 6P with the Android 7.1.1.

Comment: Your app cannot hold `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED`, as that is a `signature|privileged` permission, unless your app is signed by the firmware signing key or is installed as a system ("privileged") app. `setPairingConfirmation()` is documented as requiring `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED`, so presumably this is working as intended. I cannot explain how it worked before, and I do not know what the workaround would be, if there is one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Permission BLUETOOTH Manifest error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786291/android-permission-bluetooth-manifest-error)

Comment: Ok so the BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED permission is not available to 3th party applications I now read at the documentation. 
But when I look at the source of setPairingConfirmation() it requires BLUETOOTH_ADMIN. Maybe Google changed this in a security update...

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth permission may be turned off even if you write the permission in the manifest. The users have the right to denie some of the permission. you have to ask the users to grand the permission during runtime. this link will help you  [Android requesting permission from the user](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

you can confirm that permission is turned off or not by going to setting -> installed apps -> find your app then look for its permission

Comment: The bluetooth permissions are not runtime permissions. When I request them at runtime, they are not prompted.

Comment: did you check the permission is turned off or on inside settings

Comment: Apperantly Google changed something in a security update so that setPairingConfirmation() is not available anymore for external applications. It can only be used by approved apps and the Android system. It requires BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED now in stead of BLUETOOTH_ADMIN (before end of december 2016).
I guess I don't need the function and I misunderstood the use of it probably.

Comment: Roel, I think you are right. Idiots. Made worse because of an Android bug that does not pop up the user menu asking 'do you want to pair with this device?' when the device sends a security request.